# Not able to select angular dropdown in selenium java

Tags: java, angular, selenium

I have tried select class and also actions for selecting from dropdown, but none is working.

```html
<datalist _ngcontent-c7="" id="brow"><select _ngcontent-c7=""><option _ngcontent-c7="" value="">Select</option><!----><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Accounting Framework for Cons Reporting</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Accounting framework for solo reporting</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">AnaCredit First submission deadline</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">AnaCredit Reporting Qrtly for Counterparty Risk</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">AnaCredit Reporting Qrtly for S4</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">AnaCredit Reporting regime for T1</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">AnaCredit Reporting regime for T2</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">AnaCredit submission type</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Annual turnover</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Annual turnover domestic</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Assessment of CSPP eligibility</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Balance Sheet Total (ECB regulation) domestic</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Balance sheet total</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Balance sheet total interval</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Birthdate</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Birthdate</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Birthdate</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Birthdate</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">City</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Closedate</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Closedate</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Closedate</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Closedate</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Comment</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Country of residence</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Country of residence</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Country of residence</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Country of residence</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Date of enterprise size</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Date of initiation of legal proceedings</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Direct controlling parent RIAD ID</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Direct controlling parent RIAD code</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Economic activity</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Enterprise size</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Entity RIAD code</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Geographical scope</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Gross Premium domestic</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Gross premium</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Group Name</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Group gross premium</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Group net assets</option><!----><option _ngcontent-c7="">Group total balance sheet</option><!----></select><i _ngcontent-c7="" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></datalist>
```

Comment: show your java code as well there may be change of incorrect code as well, show what error you getting and what are your trials and errors, read [tour] and [mcve] then edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Hi,Select and Actions didn't work,This worked..
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@formcontrolname='xx']")).sendKeys(RaidLabel);
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@formcontrolname='xx']")).click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of dropdown")).sendKeys(RaidLabel);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS); driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of option")).click();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).